# Random Javascript Text Crashes, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

it only crashes when i see it "live", inside jsbin seems to be working

```
var counter = 1;
var out = function nextNum() {
counter++;
var numArray = ["1","2","3"];
$('<span id="news' + counter + '" style="display:block; width:20px; height:20px;" />')
.html( Math.floor(Math.random()*numArray.length) ).appendTo('.div1')
.hide().fadeIn(100, function(){if(counter <= 20) nextNum();});};
(out)();


setInterval(rnd,1000);
function rnd() {
var letter = ["1","2","3"];
for (var spanum = 1;; spanum++)
$( "#news" + spanum ).html( Math.floor(Math.random()*letter.length) );}
```

http://jsbin.com/IQuxevu/4/edit

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please also post the code in the question?

Comment: Perhaps use `console` ?

Comment: Please, fix your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an infinite loop in your code:

```
for (var spanum = 1;; spanum++)
```

There is no `break` inside the loop. It works on JSFiddle because there is an *infinite-loop protection* as suggested by console warnings.

Comment: right! i fixed now
         for (var spanum = 1; spanum <= 20 ; spanum++)

Comment: Very helpful answer here for looping in js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript